Ubuntu 'sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop' problem
I was downloading Ubuntu on Mac M1,
and at the last step where I download Ubuntu Desktop, and entered 'sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop' but got a problem -'failed to fetch', so I tried to solve it with
apt-get update
apt-get update --fix-missing
apt-get install xxx
apt-get upgrade

but ended up with permission issues. What should I do now?
This is the problem that happened after entering apt-get update, same happened the other commands:


also it looks like this when I enter apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
E:could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E:Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock(/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend),are you root?

Your command in the picture is invalid; you require elevated privileges to run apt-get but you didn't provide that; ie. you didn't use sudo

Is it a virtual machine running on mac m1?
